# Set Width And Height For Phone And Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

i am developing webview android app for phone and tablet, and i am using tablelayout, this is my front page

[image]

i want to set width and height that will fit to screen when comes to tablet or big screen, how can i ? this is my xml

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hindi"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/punjabi"
         />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want different layouts that will fill the screen for tablets and other big screens?
Example:

- tablets = 1 row has 3 buttons
- big screens = 1 row has 5 buttons

I think the best way to do this is to create different XML layouts for each screen size. You can have 1 layout for phones (ex. 2 buttons per row) and 1 layout for tablets (ex. 3-4 buttons per row). You can then adjust the layout separately. I suggest you read the [How to Support Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) section of the Android developer docs for more info, since I can't see you're entire XML.

Also, if you're table and `TableRow` fills-up the entire width of the screen, I suggest using `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.